# How to add only user password without owner password to a PDF using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

How to add only user password to the pdf file without adding the owner password using iText? As far as I can see, seems only can do this by adding an user password along with an owner password.

Comment: How do you expect a PDF having a user password but no owner password to behave? Anyone not identifying himself by password shall be considered the owner of the document and, thus, probably have more rights than anyone identifying hinself by user password?

Comment: This is what my customer wanted, personally I don't like doing this.

Comment: Please ask your customer to supply a sample PDF with the security settings he wants. If he provides a sample, inspect it. I would not be surprised if that PDF has both an user password and an owner password but one of them is either the default password or a random one.

Comment: What is the default owner password then? I'm confused

Comment: If you restrict permissions using the encrypted permissions but don't require the user to type a password when opening the PDF, the PDF actually is encrypted using a default user password defined in the specification (and therefore generally known). Maybe your customer or his software have implemented the use of that default password for the owner password, too. Would have to be inspected.

Comment: The specification actually says that in calculation of the relevant encryption dictionary entries: **If there is no owner password, use the user password instead** (*Algorithm 3: Computing the encryption dictionary’s O (owner password) value* in [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)). You can do that in iText by using the same password as owner and as user password. @Bruno always full of surprise, this spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encrypting an existing PDF is done like this:

```
public void encryptPdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.setEncryption(USER, OWNER,
    PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

See http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=219

If OWNER is `null`, then a random owner password will be generated (one that nobody knows). Maybe that's what your customer means. As mkl already explained, it doesn't really make sense to have a PDF with a USER password, but without an OWNER password.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, I think I'll have to accept this as the iText's limitation.

Comment: It's not an iText limitation; it's a limitation inherent to ISO-32000-1. I'm pretty sure Foxxit has the same limitation; maybe they use a standard owner password (which is something you also can do).

Comment: What is a standard owner password? Sorry, I'm not an expert of PDF, so do enlighten me.

Comment: Maybe Foxxit has chosen a 32-character password that is shipped with Foxxit, and maybe they are always using the same password.

Comment: Problem is that I don't have this password, I think I'll have to use my own standard password, etc, :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code is what you need to add the owner password.

```
  JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();       
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperprintobj);
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE,new File(fileName));
  exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.IS_ENCRYPTED, Boolean.TRUE);
  exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.IS_128_BIT_KEY, Boolean.TRUE);
  //exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.USER_PASSWORD, "jasper");
  exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OWNER_PASSWORD, "reports");
  exporter.setParameter(
    JRPdfExporterParameter.PERMISSIONS, 
    new Integer(PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY | PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING)
    );
  exporter.exportReport(); // finally export as pdf
```

Use this code in java where you generate the pdf.

Comment: adding encryption is upto you. but is a security feature I recommend

Comment: I'm not adding owner password, my customer only wants to add user password. He says that certain software like foxit can do this, thus we need to add it. And I'm talking about adding to existing PDFs, not generating new one